# The math in the article: Metcalfe's law is wrong

Tags: network

In this article: [Metcalfe's law is wrong](https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/networks/metcalfes-law-is-wrong)

There is a calculation:

> Imagine a network of 100 000 members that we know brings in $1 million.
>
> So if the network doubles its membership to 200 000
>
> Metcalfe’s law says its value grows by (200 000^2 /100 000^2 ) times, quadrupling to $4 million
>
> Whereas the n*log(n) law says its value grows by 200 000*log(200 000)/100 000*log(100 000) times to only $2.1 million.

My questions are:

- Why grows by (200 000^2 /100 000^2) times? The Metcalfe’s Law is as simple as n^2, how come there is a division ?
- How does the $4 million been calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why grows by (200 000^2 /100 000^2) times? The Metcalfe’s Law is as simple as n^2, how come there is a division ?

Because Metcalfe's law is used for calculating the proportional value of a network based on the "number of connections." In the article they are calculating the percentage of growth. So you take the new value and divide it by the old value.

> How does the $4 million been calculated?

Because 200,000<sup>2</sup>/100,000<sup>2</sup> gives you an answer of 400% or 4 times the original value. 4 * 1 = 4

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't 2000,000^2/100,000^2 = 2, so, it's 2 times?

Comment: How is 40,000,000/10,000,000 = 2?

Comment: Ah..... I've been stupid... Now it's all clear... thanks!

Comment: One more Q, the n*log(n) law, is it log10 or log2?

Comment: I asume it is log10, and the math seems to bear that out.

Answer (score 1):

If I $\times2$ the amount of users, I expect to $\times4$ the revenue.

$4=2^2$.

In this case, $\displaystyle \frac{2 \,\,\text{million}}{1 \,\,\text{million}}=2$.

The division is to find the growth in membership. Square the membership growth to get revenue growth.

Comment: Not sure where you are getting 2 million/1 million?

Comment: oh sorry, i meant 200,000/100,000